# Can I Get the Unity Desktop Terminal on Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: unity, gnome

I'm currently running Ubuntu GNOME, but I really would like to know if I can get the standard purple backgrounded terminal that comes with the "regular" Ubuntu install and the Unity Desktop. My terminal works fine; I just think that the Unity terminal is nicer to look at.

[image: Here's a link to the terminal that I'm talking about.]

Comment: [This article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/solarized-must-have-color-paletter-for.html) describes how to set the colors for the terminals

Comment: That article describes how to set the colors, but I'm looking to get my terminal as close to the Unity default colorscheme as possible.

Comment: Indeed - you would need to find what the colors are, and then set them to match.

Answer (score 5):

They are actually the same (gnome-terminal), but with different color schemes.

If you have the Unity desktop, first create a new temporary user and login with it into Unity. Run a terminal and close it. Now log off and access GNOME with your regular user again. Open a terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal
sudo cp -rf /home/tmp-username/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal $HOME/.gconf/apps
```

replacing `tmp-username` with the name of the temporary user you just created. After running the command you can delete this user. Run gnome-terminal again and now you should see the Unity style.

Comment: Ah, well does that mean that I could make them look/act the same if I copied their settings? Is there somewhere that I could find that?

Comment: Ok. I'll do this. I'm definitely making a GitHub repo for this if this works.

Comment: Eduardo, I installed `ubuntu-desktop` package and then tried to open up a terminal, but it looks like the terminal that gets installed with the `ubuntu-desktop` package doesn't have the same color scheme as the ubuntu terminal of the picture in my original question. Should I just try and ask someone to give me a copy of their terminal settings?

To be clear -- I created a new user, logged out, and then logged into that new user that I created after selecting `Ubuntu` desktop in the GNOME Display Manager login.